# Built-in class to serialize/deserialize a set of flags

Tags: .net

I need to store an array of flags in a string.  I was looking at using BitArray, but noticed that there is no built-in method to write to/read from a char[] or int[] or something.  I can write this code easily enough, but I'd prefer to use a built-in method if there is one out there.

So are there built-in .NET methods that handle this?

Comment: A code snippet relating to your problem may assist in getting a better answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

If your flags are represented as a defined enum, you can simply cast it to one of the integral types that enums support (int, long, etc). You can then deserialize the enum from its value representation using:

```
// define a Flags enumeration...
[Flags] enum MyEnum { First = 1, Second = 2, Third = 4, };


MyEnum originalValue = MyEnum.First | MyEnum.Second;
int storedValue = (int)originalValue;  

// value serialized into storage somewhere...

// later on ...
// deserialized however you need...
int restoredValue = ReadValueFromDataStore(); 
// convert back into a typesafe enum...
MyEnum recoveredValue = Enum.Parse( typeof(MyEnum), restoredValue );
```

Comment: Actually, it is possible to use originalValue.ToString() and Enum.Parse to serialize and deserialize the value - the intermediate int isn't needed.  Is there a reason the intermediate int is needed?

Answer (score 0):

The [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class has some of this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) does support Int32[], you can use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3d1dwck.aspx) that accepts an int[] for initialization, and [CopyTo(Array array, Int32 index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.copyto.aspx). The current CopyTo implementation supports writing to Boolean[], Byte[] and Int32[] according to msdn.